# Using bibtex to reference dissertation

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, texmaker

I'm currently trying to reference my dissertation. I have created a file called reference.bib and have used the tools in bibtex to create a list of sources that I have used.

I have tried to integrate these references into my work (written in texmaker) but the reference is coming up like this (??) and when I put this command,

\bibliographystyle{plain}

\bibliography{reference}

\end{document}

nothing is showing up? Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong - this is the first time I've used tex? Thank you

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-instead-of-citation-number help?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I don't really understand what I'm doing with it. I have my references (that I want to refer to ) saved as a 'reference.bib' file in the same folder as my dissertation.tex file

But when I use this command 

\bibliographystyle{plain}
   \bibliography{reference.bib}

just before \end{document} nothing shows up. And where I've tried to reference something, for example "....... \ref{curvedef} I just get a question mark, and I don't understand why

Comment: As described in the link I've given, have you run LaTeX, then BibTeX, then LaTeX again twice? Citations are a two-part procedure and require that BibTeX gets run.

Comment: I've just tried that, the bit at the bottom where I input the \bibliography{reference.bib} now says 'References' but that's it, doesn't actually have the list of references, and the bit where I tried to cite it, is still a question mark. When you say 'run LaTex.....' do you mean just open the documents?

Comment: With the main `.tex` file open, the sequence you require is : run LaTeX, run BibTeX, run LaTeX, run LaTeX: all should have the 'main file' as the focus. It's only on the last run that any citations will be fully resolved. (I presume you have one or more `\cite` commands in the document.)

Comment: Okay, this may seem like a really silly question, but how do I r'run' it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13474/discussion-between-joseph-wright-and-sarah-jayne)

Comment: Open a (command) shell. Within the shell go to the folder with your file `dissertation.tex`. Run the commands `pdflatex dissertation`, `bibtex dissertation`, `pdflatex dissertation`, `pdflatex dissertation` sequentially.

Comment: On the basis of chat, I'm closing as a dupe: this is the 'run BibTeX then LaTex again' issue.